# React-native - How to begin StackNavigator on certain level

Tags: react-native, navigation

I have only one screen and call itself.

```
module.exports = StackNavigator({
    Parent: { screen: PickCategory },
})
```

Currently, i navigate to screen level i want on `componentWillMount`.
But i can see the transition, it's ugly and annoying.

I wanna load StackNavigator with specified level without animation.
Is it posible?

Answer (score 0):

Put your screen level want on the first param in StackNavigator.

```
const TideTable = StackNavigator({
Home: { screen: YourScreenLevelYouWantToDisplayFirst},
Second: { screen: NextScreen},
Third: { screen: TheNextOne},
```

});

Comment: I only have one screen (StackNavigator screen can call itself)